# Guarding function declaration not compiling

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am guarding functions in my header file with a #define which I add as a  global compile flag with make through the command line. This is to decrease the overall binary size when I am not using certain code.

I thought I could just guard them in the header file and the functions in the c file would be automatically compiled out. This is not compiling for me. Make is reporting that function is undeclared. I have to place guards around the functions in the C file as well to make it compile ok.

Is this expected behavior or should guarding the function declaration suffice.

Header File

```
#ifndef __LOGIC_H__
#define __LOGIC_H__

#include "test.h"

#if (HAS_SPI)
int test_spi_config(void);
int test_spi_transfer(void);
#endif
#endif /* __LOGIC_H__ */
```

C File

```
#include "logic.h"

#if (HAS_SPI) /* Wont compile without this */
int test_spi_config(void) {
     /* code */
}
#if (HAS_SPI) /* Wont compile without this */
int test_spi_transfer(void) {
     /* code */
}
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: you have to post contents of `test.h`. Also there's a new way of protecting includes with `#pragma once`.

Comment: You want to replace the `#if` with `#ifdef`

Comment: and please post the error.

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre I did it says function undeclared

Comment: I'd rather see the real output.

Comment: Note that the header does not provide prototypes for the `test_spi_*()` functions; it only provides declarations.  Those declarations say "the function exists; the function returns an `int`; there is no information about the number or types of the arguments — except that it doesn't use ellipsis (`...`) for variadic arguments".  To make a prototype in C for a function taking zero arguments, you must write `int test_spi_config(void);` with the `void`.  The rules in C++ are different, but this is a C question.

Comment: How is `HAS_SPI` defined?  `#define HAS_SPI 1`?  `-DHAS_SPI=1`?  `-DHAS_SPI`?  It isn't defined?  The value is `0` instead of `1`?  My guess is that you've not defined `HAS_SPI`, so the preprocessor treats it as zero, and `#if 0` doesn't include the declarations from the header, or define the code in the source files.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I defined it using this. `-DHAS_SPI=1` It works if I include the guards in the c file so it is defined.

Comment: Declarations don't generate code.

Answer (score 0):

#### Preprocessor functionality

The preprocessor does simple text transformations.  It doesn't understand C very much at all.  In particular, it has no understanding of declarations or definitions of functions; it doesn't know or care whether the text it is parsing is part of a function or not, and especially it doesn't know which function it is processing.

I think you are expecting that if the header has:

```
#if HAS_SPI
extern int test_spi_config(void);
#endif
```

and the implementation file has:

```
int test_spi_config(void)
{
    …
    return 0;
}
```

then the compiler proper won't be shown the code for `test_spi_config()` because the header didn't declare it.

This is a inaccurate expectation.  The preprocessor doesn't see a line started by `#` around the function definition, and there are no macros in this discussion that would change the text of the source code (no `#define test_spi_config() rand()`, for example), so the function definitions are simply copied through to the main compiler.

The function definition must itself be protected by an equivalent (preferably, the same) condition as the prototype declarations:

```
#if HAS_SPI
int test_spi_config(void)
{
    …
    return 0;
}
#endif
```

So, in your question, the conditionally defined prototypes in the header do not affect the text around the function; you need the explicit tests.

You should also enclose every call to `test_spi_config()` or `test_spi_transfer()` in an appropriate `#if HAS_SPI` / `#endif` condition.  This may have an effect on the surrounding logic, so the block enclosed may be larger than the single function call — especially if you need to test or save the return value from `test_spi_config()` (and, if you don't, why is the function returning a value in the first place?).

#### Notation

```
#if HAS_SPI
```

Note that these conditions are often written as `#ifdef HAS_SPI` or `#if defined(HAS_SPI)` so that it does not matter what `HAS_SPI` is defined to.  With the `#if` condition, if you have `#define HAS_SPI 0` somewhere (or the command line equivalent), then the code will be omitted, whereas with the `defined` variants, it will be included.  Which is correct depends on your needs — but it is more common to use `#ifdef` than `#if`.

It is more important to be consistent — always use `#if` or always use `#ifdef`— than which is used.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is absolutely normal.

C compiler see **declarations** of `test_spi_*` functions and emits stub code for each .c file that includes logic.h. But at the linking stage **definitions** of these functions aren't found, because they are omitted by preprocessor. Thus, linking errors.

Comment: I doubt that's the case here. #if conditions are the same in .h and .c.

Comment: So this is normal, you will need to put guards in c file as well as header file correct?

Comment: @homeGrown If you want to save a space - yes.

Comment: What do you mean by 'emits stub code for each `.c` file'?  That isn't something I recognize as normal terminology for anything that a C compiler does.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wanted to say that every .c file that has a declaration for these functions would end up with a references to them in its corresponding object file. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: The object file only contains references to functions (or variables) that are used by the code that it compiles.  If you have a reference to `test_spi_config()` that is excluded by the preprocessor, then the object file will not contain a reference to `test_spi_config()`.  This is just as well, really, when you think about it.  If it wasn't like that, every function mentioned in every system header included by a source file would be referenced from the object file, which would make for enormous programs wholly unnecessarily — especially if using static libraries rather than shared libraries.